# OLE: Inaccessible due to its protection level. 

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ole

I am trying to plot a chart in excel sheet using VB.

So now I am following the instructions given  [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142387)

1- I started a new VB project in VS2010, called Excelgraph.

2- By default I got Form1.vb[Design].

3- On this Form I created a button by dragging it from the toolbox.

4-I doubled clicked it and new Form1.vb opens.

5- I removed everything that was automatically generated in this file i,e Form1.vb file and pasted the following code:

**Updated Code**

This is another code and is a latest one, compatible with Visual Basic 6.0.

```
 Public Class Form1



  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
  System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim oXL As Object        ' Excel application
    Dim oBook As Object      ' Excel workbook
    Dim oSheet As Object     ' Excel Worksheet
    Dim oChart As Object     ' Excel Chart

    Dim iRow As Integer      ' Index variable for the current Row
    Dim iCol As Integer      ' Index variable for the current Row

    Const cNumCols = 10      ' Number of points in each Series
    Const cNumRows = 2       ' Number of Series


    ReDim aTemp(0 To cNumRows, 0 To cNumCols)

    'Start Excel and create a new workbook
    oXL = CreateObject("Excel.application")
    oBook = oXL.Workbooks.Add
    oSheet = oBook.Worksheets.Item(1)

    ' Insert Random data into Cells for the two Series:
    Randomize(Now().ToOADate())
    For iRow = 1 To cNumRows
        For iCol = 1 To cNumCols
            aTemp(iRow, iCol) = Int(Rnd() * 50) + 1
        Next iCol
    Next iRow
    oSheet.Range("A1").Resize(cNumRows, cNumCols).Value = aTemp

    'Add a chart object to the first worksheet
    oChart = oSheet.ChartObjects.Add(50, 40, 300, 200).Chart
    oChart.SetSourceData(Source:=oSheet.Range("A1").Resize(cNumRows, cNumCols))

    ' Make Excel Visible:
    oXL.Visible = True

    oXL.UserControl = True

    End Sub



End Class
```

**Update**

I updated the code as shown above.

**Error**

```
    'aTemp' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.    
     c:\users\ybf4 \documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Excelgraph2
     \Excelgraph2\Form1.vb
```

There were two more errors which I managed to remove. How do I remove this error?

I am compiling the above code on visual studio 2010 and Office is Office 2007.

Comment: You're following a guide that was written for Visual Basic 3 and Excel 5?

Comment: Now I am following a latest code. Any suggestions??

Comment: I think I have to change the scope of aTemp. But how ?

Answer (score 3):

A simple, trivial program reveals the error to be as I suspected - you can't change the size of something that doesn't exist!

As Derek said, you need to change the ReDim to Dim - OR you need to declare it first.

**FAILS:**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Const cNumCols = 10      ' Number of points in each Series
    Const cNumRows = 2       ' Number of Series

    ReDim aTemp(0 To cNumRows, 0 To cNumCols)
End Sub
```

**PASSES:**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Const cNumCols = 10      ' Number of points in each Series
    Const cNumRows = 2       ' Number of Series
    Dim aTemp

    ReDim aTemp(0 To cNumRows, 0 To cNumCols)
End Sub
```

**PASSES:**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Const cNumCols = 10      ' Number of points in each Series
    Const cNumRows = 2       ' Number of Series

    Dim aTemp(0 To cNumRows, 0 To cNumCols)
End Sub
```

Hovering over aTemp should have told you this - it should also be underlined by a blue squiggly line to indicate a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since I did this, but just looking at the code I suspect you need to change:

```
ReDim aTemp(0 To cNumRows, 0 To cNumCols)
```

To:

```
Dim aTemp(0 To cNumRows, 0 To cNumCols)
```

ReDim is used to re-dimension an array after it has been dimensioned (using the Dim statement)

Answer (score 0):

That's remarkably old code (it's for VB3, so 4 generations before the first VB.Net, and Excel 5)

However, I believe your code should run fine if you just comment out the two lines indicated.

The randomness of the entries added to the worksheet may be different, but since you'll be replacing that code anyway (where `Rnd()` is used), it shouldn't matter. (I'm assuming your purpose isn't to generate random graphs)

As to `DoEvents`, I'm not sure that was ever necessary.

Comment: If you were doing something that was cpu intensive enough, the GUI would freeze. DoEvents solved that problem. An ugly solution in an ugly language for an ugly problem, me-thinks. But a solution all the same. :)